# How to loop over dynamically generated buttons and create input field accordingly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to loop over dynamically generated buttons that has got identical Id for some, and different Id for others,
and create input fields that has value according to the number of buttons.

All buttons has the same class name so that we can use it to loop over them.

**For instance :**

*I got 5 dynamically generated buttons on the page,*

*3 with identical Id like "55",*

*and the rest 2 with different Id each other like "14" and "7".*

***So here it has to create 3 buttons.***

dynamically created button 1 (Id = 55) must have value 3  (because there are 3 buttons with Id 55)

dynamically created button 2 (Id = 14) must have value 1  (because there is only 1 button with Id 14)

dynamically created button 3 (Id = 7) must have value 1  (because there is only 1 button with Id 7)

*(I know that Id must be unique but I just found it like that, so  I'm just maintaining the app for few month adding 2 new features, I'm not allowed to touch anything else as the senior architect dev told me)*

```
("#btn-save").click(function () {

    var count = 0;

    // Loop over the Id of all these buttons
    $("#btn-add-vehicle-item").each(function () {

        $("<input class='" + btn-class + "' value='" + myvalue + "' name='VehicleInvoice[" + count + "].VehicleSold' type='hidden' />").insertAfter('#main_div');
        
        count++;
        
    });

});
```

PS : I'm working on a many to many relationship and cannot have multiple identical Id in the joint table on the Key value side, EF Core is giving this error **The instance of entity type 'pppp' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for table...**  that's why I added a row *Quantity Sold* in the joint table to hold item number.
I'm following this MS Access tutorial [here](https://www.gct.com.au/SampleFiles/AccessXP/accxp_ch10.pdf)

Comment: But... identical IDs are not allowed. That's what IDs are for in a document. To give exclusive selector rights to one single element. Wouldn't it be a mess if more people had your same insurance number, or telephone number? Please, read more about ID selectors https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#id-selectors

Comment: If for some reason you need to store some data into an Element's attribute, well use the `data-*` attribute instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  Can `data-*` post data like we post using input form ?

Comment: (Offtopic) *"Vehicule"* is misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique. Use `data-*` attribute instead. And instruct your senior architect that such issues should be fixed.

Here's an example with those "five buttons" but let's see how to handle that task with the proper `data-` attributes in place:

```js
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const ELS_buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-id]");
const IDS_count = [...ELS_buttons].reduce((ob, el) => {
  if (!ob[el.dataset.id]) ob[el.dataset.id] = 1;
  else ob[el.dataset.id]++;
  return ob;
}, {}); // Will give us something like: {"7": 1, "14": 1, "55": 3}

const ELS_inputs = Object.entries(IDS_count).reduce((DF, [k, v], i) => {
  DF.append(ELNew("input", {
    class: "my-hidden-input",
    title: `Index: ${i} Vehicle ID: ${k} Value: ${v}`,
    value: v,
    name: `VehiculeInvoice[${i}].VehiculeSold`,
    // hidden: true
  }))
  return DF;
}, new DocumentFragment);

document.querySelector("#mainDiv").append(ELS_inputs);
```

```css
#mainDiv {padding:10px background: #eee;}
```

```html
<!-- Dynamically generated buttons example -->
<button data-id="55" type="button">55</button>
<button data-id="14" type="button">14</button>
<button data-id="7" type="button">7</button>
<button data-id="55" type="button">55</button>
<button data-id="55" type="button">55</button>

<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to create a list of unique IDs:

```js
const mainDiv = document.getElementById("main_div");
/* generating buttons */
const btnClass = "test";
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  button.className = btnClass;
  button.textContent = "id" + button.id;
  mainDiv.appendChild(button);
}

/* get all buttons */
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.test");
const count = {};

//loop through buttons and generate list of unique IDs
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
  count[buttons[i].id] = ~~count[buttons[i].id] + 1; //increase count for each id

// loop through unique IDs.
for(let c in count)
{
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  input.className = btnClass;
//  input.type = "hidden";
  input.name = "VehiculeInvoice[" + count[c] + "].VehiculeSold";
  input.value = count[c];//myvalue?

  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.appendChild(input);
  span.dataset.id = c; //this will be displayed from CSS
  mainDiv.appendChild(span);
}
console.log(count);
/*
$("#btn-save").click(function () {

    var count = 0;

    // Loop over the Id of all these buttons
    $("#btn-add-vehicule-item").each(function () {

        $("<input class='" + btn-class + "' value='" + myvalue + "' name='VehiculeInvoice[" + count + "].VehiculeSold' type='hidden' />").insertAfter('#main_div');
        
        count++;
        
    });

});
*/
```

```css
span
{
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span:before
{
  content: "id" attr(data-id) "=";
}
```

```html
<div id="main_div"></div>
```